# onClick not respond for hide() and show() function

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, hide, show

sorry everyone, i have a question. why function didn't respond?

my html :

```
<img id="btn" src="img/button.png" onclick="show()"></img>
...
<img id="xxx" src=""></img>
```

my script :

```
function show(){
    document.getElementById("xxx").src = "img/src.png";
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = "hide()";
}
function hide(){
    document.getElementById("xxx").src = "";
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = "show()";
}
```

if i click the button, only first function [`function show()`] which respond. please help. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best solution to change onclick handler every time.
Let your click handling code be in one place:

HTML:

```
<img id="btn" src="img/button.png" onclick="clickHandler()"></img>

<img id="xxx" src=""></img>
```

And Javascript:

```
function clickHandler() {
  var img = document.getElementById("xxx");
  img.src = !img.src ? "img/src.png" : "";
}
```

**UPDATE:** (in reply to comment of @nathoenk) Anyway, you chouldn't swap event handlers on each user click. You can, for example, create global variable to hold current state of your 'show/hide' logic.

```
var imagesAreHidden = true;
function clickHandler() {
  if (imagesAreHidden) {
    // do "show" logic
    document.getElementById("xxx1").src = "img/src1.png";
    document.getElementById("xxx2").src = "img/src2.png";
    document.getElementById("xxx3").src = "img/src3.png";
  } else {
    // hide"
    document.getElementById("xxx1").src = "";
    document.getElementById("xxx2").src = "";
    document.getElementById("xxx3").src = "";        
  }
  imagesAreHidden = !imagesAreHidden; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your respond, but my real code is

`function show(){
document.getElementById("xxx1").src = "img/src1.png";
document.getElementById("xxx2").src = "img/src2.png";
document.getElementById("xxx3").src = "img/src3.png";
...
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = "hide()";
}`

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the reference to the function directly. Not the name of the function.

```
function show(){
    document.getElementById("xxx").src = "img/src.png";
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = hide;
}

function hide(){
    document.getElementById("xxx").src = "";
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = show;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

just use this line :
    document.getElementById("btn").onclick = hide;

do that with jQuery rather than javascript,first add class "show" to your btn :

```
$('.show').click(function(){$('#xxx').attr('src','img/src.png');$(this).addClass=('hide');$(this).removeClass('show')});
$('.hide').click(function(){$('#xxx').attr('src','');$(this).addClass=('show');$(this).removeClass('hide')})
```

Comment: 1. No jQuery tag means no jQuery answers. 2. Your jQuery code is wrong and displays a lack of understanding of how selectors and direct events work. 3. Formatting!

Comment: @Shirin thanks for your respond, but like Anthony says, without jQuery

Comment: sorry for the formatting,I'm new here,but as you can see first I told you how to fix your code then I add jQery codes,